# Latex, having two lists of something on the one page

Tags: list, latex

I am writing my thesis right now and I have fallowing problem, I have couple of lists. List of figures, list of algorithms, list of listings... etc. Most of them are very short, but each of them takes whole page. So I have couple of lists which only list few things on one page, and the rest of the page is blank.

How can I put two lists on one page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer here:
http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~anup/homepage/UNIX/latex.html#lotandlof

So I wrote something like that:

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{1\linewidth}
    \listofalgorithms
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b]{1\linewidth}
    \listoffigures
\end{minipage}
```

Right now if there is enough space two lists can be put on one page.

Answer (score 1):

Just write the lists one after the other. If enough space is available, they will be put on the same page: lists don’t include page breaks.

Comment: There was enough space, but each of them takes whole page. Maybe I had some different style of document or something.

Answer (score 1):

You say this is for a thesis? Most thesis styles require each list to be on separate pages. I would first double check your thesis style guide. Further, many Universities provide thesis class files (some_thesis_name.cls) which automatically follow the style guide. Check it out, you may save a lot of time and worry.

Comment: You are right. But my University did not give anything like that, and they require from to have couple of lists on one page.